# Why is paintComponent not displaying correctly?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

When running my program, sometimes the the triangles are drawn, sometimes they aren't, and sometimes only the last one appears. Originally I put the code in a **for** loop, but it didn't work, so I tried to go backwards and write it all out instead to see if it works, but to no avail. The correct behavior should be, displaying five triangles, equally spaced on the screen (Directly below the top rectangle). I tried printing out the array, but the number of times the **println()** method was called was sort of random, instead of constant. I heard that the **paintComponent()** method can be called at any time by the Swing Framework, but I'm not sure. Essentially I'm asking, why the triangles (the cyan ones) aren't being drawn correctly, and how do I fix it?

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GraphicsClass extends JPanel {

    private int[] xCoordinates = {20, 40, 30};
    private int[] yCoordinates = {40, 40, 60};

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 450, 40);
        g.fillRect(0, 260, 450, 40);

        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillPolygon(xCoordinates, yCoordinates, 3);
        xCoordinates[0] += 95;
        xCoordinates[1] += 95;
        xCoordinates[2] += 95;
        g.fillPolygon(xCoordinates, yCoordinates, 3);
        xCoordinates[0] += 95;
        xCoordinates[1] += 95;
        xCoordinates[2] += 95;
        g.fillPolygon(xCoordinates, yCoordinates, 3);
        xCoordinates[0] += 95;
        xCoordinates[1] += 95;
        xCoordinates[2] += 95;
        g.fillPolygon(xCoordinates, yCoordinates, 3);
        xCoordinates[0] += 95;
        xCoordinates[1] += 95;
        xCoordinates[2] += 95;
        g.fillPolygon(xCoordinates, yCoordinates, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  That code would require imports and a `main(String)` to put it on-screen to be an MCVE/SSCCE.

Comment: Your code generates a compiler error, because `Graphics` is already defined...

Comment: Please clearly define what the correct behavior is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it this way.  `paintComponent` may be called any time (upwards of four times when the component is first painted on the screen in some cases).  So each time it is called, you're adding `95` to each of the `xCoordinates`, this would make `xCoordinates[0]` equal to `400` after `paintComponent` is called the first time, `800` after the second time, so on and so fourth...

Instead, you need to make a copy of the `xCoordinates` and modify it instead, for example...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private int[] xCoordinates = {20, 40, 30};
    private int[] yCoordinates = {40, 40, 60};

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 450, 40);
        g.fillRect(0, 260, 450, 40);

        int[] xPosy = Arrays.copyOf(xCoordinates, xCoordinates.length);
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {

            g.fillPolygon(xPosy, yCoordinates, 3);
            xPosy[0] += 95;
            xPosy[1] += 95;
            xPosy[2] += 95;

        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you could forgo some of the oddities and just make use of the 2D Graphics `Shape` API

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private Polygon triangle;

    public TestPane() {
        triangle = new Polygon(new int[]{20, 40, 30}, new int[]{40, 40, 60}, 3);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 450, 40);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 260, 450, 40);

        g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, 0);
        for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {

            Shape shape = at.createTransformedShape(triangle);
            g2d.fill(shape);
            at.translate(95, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1+, I like the Shape solution. You can have lots of fun with Shapes.

Comment: @camickr I really like the Shape's API

Comment: May I also ask why I can't use an enhanced **for** loop inside of paintComponent()?

Comment: @user3477016 For the same reason as the answer, each time you update the value in the array, it's value "sticks" to that value...